# Internal error occured in parsing hprof file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-memory-analyzer

[image]

Using MemoryAnalyzer(eclipse plugin) for checking memory.
I can able to generate hprof file , but not able to open in eclipse.
Getting following internal error.

Comment: It seems that you have memory problems while analyzing a memory problem... You may want to increase memory for Eclipse : https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory analyzer itself ran out of memory when opening the `hprof` file.

From the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#Out_of_Memory_Error_while_Running_the_Memory_Analyzer):

> Well, analyzing big heap dumps can also require more heap space. Give
>   it some more memory (possible by running on a 64-bit machine):

```
MemoryAnalyzer.exe -vmargs -Xmx4g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

> Alternatively, edit the MemoryAnalyzer.ini to contain:

```
-vmargs
-Xmx2g
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

...

> If you are running the Memory Analyzer inside your Eclipse SDK, you
>   need to edit the eclipse.ini file.

Comment: I am running the Memory Analyzer inside Eclipse SDK.  what to add in eclipse.ini . I have following settings,            -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m